# JavaScript Super.prop in object literals

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, super

```
let proto = {
    whoami() { console.log('I am proto'); } 
};
let obj = { 
    whoami() { 
        Object.getPrototypeOf( obj ).whoami.call( this ); // super.whoami();
        console.log('I am obj'); 
    } 
};
Object.setPrototypeOf( obj, proto );
```

This code lets **obj** inherit the **proto**.
I got confused about this code `Object.getPrototypeOf( obj ).whoami.call( this );` which is equvalent to `super.whoami()`. Can anyone explain how this code works?

Comment: What do you find confusing about it? Getting the prototype, calling the `call` function on the property `whoami` (which itself is a function), or passing the argument `this`?

Comment: I am confused about the property whoami. Is it the property of obj or the proto? Why not use the proto.call(this), like use method from other class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to first read about the following topics in my answer below before skipping to *the explanation*:

- Prototypes

  - (Prototype-chain)
  - Property shadowing
- Functions

  - (Pure and impure functions)
  - Closures
  - `this` context

## Prototypes

### Prototype-chain

In JavaScript, objects can have [prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). An object inherits all the properties of its prototype. Since prototypes themselves are objects, they too can have prototypes. This is called the prototype-chain.

Accessing an object's property will cause JS to first try to find it on the object itself, and then on each of its prototypes consecutively.

#### Example

Let's define both a person and their prototype `human`:

```js
const human = { isSelfAware: true };
const person = { name: "john" };
Object.setPrototypeOf(person, human);
```

If we try to access `person.name`, then JS will return the property of `person` because it has this property defined.

If we however try to access `person.isSelfAware`, JS will return the property of `human` because `person` doesn't have the property defined but its prototype does.

### Property shadowing

If an object has a similarly named property as one of its prototypes, the prototype's property is shadowed, because JS will return the earliest defined property.

Shadowing is useful because objects can define different property values without affecting the prototype.

#### Example

```js
const lightBulbProto = { serialNumber: 12345, isFunctional: true };
const oldLightBulb = { isFunctional: false };
const newLightBulb = {};
Object.setPrototypeOf(oldLightBulb , lightBulbProto);
Object.setPrototypeOf(newLightBulb, lightBulbProto);
```

By default, all light bulbs are functional. But now we defined an old light bulb to be non-functional (`isFunctional: false`).

This doesn't affect `newLightBulb` because we didn't define the functionality on the prototype, but on the specific object `oldLightBulb`.

## Functions

First off: By "function" I only mean functions and function expressions `function() {}`. Method definitions are syntactic sugar for function expressions, so they are considered the same. Arrow function expressions `() => {}` are excluded.

### Types of functions

If a function is deterministic (same input results in same output) and self-enclosed (no side-effects), it is a pure function; otherwise it is an impure function.

Pure functions are usually easy to understand and debug, since all relevant code is contained in its definition.

```js
const array = [];
function addToArray(o) { // Impure function
  array.push(o);
}

function add(a, b) { // Pure function
  return a + b;
}
```

### Scope and closures

JS tries to bundle your function with the smallest possible scope. If your function uses variables outside of its own scope, a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) is created at function creation during runtime. This means, the surrounding scope is kept alive for as long as the dependent function is accessible.

Closures aren't inherently bad, but may be confusing or cause of a memory-leak.

#### Example

`createGet` initializes `object` in its scope, and then returns a getter for the object:

```js
function createGet() {
  const object = {};
  return function() {
    return object;
  }
}

let get1 = createGet();
let get2 = createGet();

// They are independent!
get1().name = "get1";
get2().number = 2;

console.log(get1()); // { "name": "get1" }
console.log(get2()); // { "number": 2 }

// Release the closures!
get1 = undefined;
get2 = undefined;
```

The code looks as if each getter function returns the same object. This is not true, because every call of `createGet` initializes a different object each time. Because of this, each getter function refers to a different object, making each getter independent.

Since closures may bundle a different scope at every creation, they may be a memory-leak. Only when no further reference to a closure exists, it may be garbage-collected. In our example we do this with these lines:

```js
get1 = undefined;
get2 = undefined;
```

### Strict-mode

Apart from the default "sloppy mode", JS also features a [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

### `this` context

The current context is effectively the value of `this` in the current scope.

The context of a function is determined by how the function is called. A function may be called standalone (e.g. `aFunc()`) or as a method (e.g. `obj.aMethod()`).

If a function is called on its own, it inherits the surrounding context. If there is no surrounding function context, the surrounding context will either be `globalThis` in "sloppy mode", or be `undefined` in strict mode.

If the function is called as a method `obj.aMethod()`, `this` will refer to `obj`.

Additionally, the first argument of the functions [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) can specify the context of the underlying function.

```js
console.log("Global context:");
(function() {
  console.log("- Sloppy: this == globalThis? " + (this === globalThis));
  // In browsers: globalThis == window
})();
(function() {
  "use strict";
  console.log("- Strict: this == undefined? " + (this === undefined));
})();

const compareThis = function(o) {
  return this === o;
};
const obj = { compareThis };

console.log("As function:");
console.log("- Default: this == obj? " + compareThis(obj));
console.log("- With call(obj): this == obj? " + compareThis.call(obj, obj));

console.log("As method:");
console.log("- Default: this == obj? " + obj.compareThis(obj));
console.log("- With call(undefined): this == obj? " + obj.compareThis.call(undefined, obj));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:unset !important}
```

## Finally: The explanation

First, two objects (`obj` and `proto`) are initialized. `proto` will be the prototype of `obj`.

Because both objects have the property `whoami` defined, the prototype's property will be shadowed. Since we still want to access the prototype's property, we have to access it directly. To do this, we first get the prototype of `obj` (`Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)`, or "`super`"), and then access its property (`.whoami`, or "`super.whoami`").

Since `whoami` was originally called on `obj`, it would make sense to use `obj` as the context. For this reason, we call `whoami.call(this)` (with `this` equal to `obj`; effectively "`super.whoami()`") on the prototype's `whoami` method, because if we didn't the method would use the prototype as its context.

Because `obj` is part of the surrounding lexical scope instead of the scope of `obj.whoami`, `whoami` creates a closure because of it using the identifier `obj` in `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)`. Ideally we would get the prototype using `this` instead, to not have an unnecessary closure: `Object.getPrototypeOf(this)`.

Comment: Thank you, I finally understand the prototype chain. Basically obj.__proto__.whoami.call(this) will do the same thing.

Comment: Yes, but [`Object.prototype.__proto__`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-additional-properties-of-the-object.prototype-object) is a legacy feature, and its usage is [discouraged by the ECMAScript specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-additional-ecmascript-features-for-web-browsers).